# How to animate UITableViewCell using Swift?

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, animation

I have a UITableView and inside the  tableViewCell I have a UICollectionView.

My requirement is while tapping on a button of first tableView cell I have to animate  second tableViewCell.

Below is my code :-

```
 //Cell For Row at indexPath
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

    if (0 == indexPath.section) {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "FirstRowCell") as! FirstRowCell
        cell.btnReview.addTarget(self, action: #selector(GotoReview), for: UIControlEvents.touchUpInside)
        cell.btnMyProduct.addTarget(self, action: #selector(AnimateCollectionView), for: UIControlEvents.touchUpInside)
        //cell.

        return cell
    } else if ( 1 == indexPath.section) {
        let identifier = "TableCollectionCell"
        var tableCollectionCell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: identifier) as? TableCollectionCell

        if(tableCollectionCell == nil) {
            let nib:Array = Bundle.main.loadNibNamed("TableCollectionCell", owner: self, options: nil)!
            tableCollectionCell = nib[0] as? TableCollectionCell
            tableCollectionCell?.delegate = self
        }

        return tableCollectionCell!
    } else {
        let identifier = "BrandImagesTableCell"
        var brandImagesTableCell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: identifier)

        if(brandImagesTableCell == nil) {
            let nib:Array = Bundle.main.loadNibNamed("BrandImagesTableCell", owner: self, options: nil)!
            brandImagesTableCell = nib[0] as? BrandImagesTableCell
          }

        //brandImagesTableCell.
        return brandImagesTableCell!
    }
}
```

In my code you can see:

```
        if (0 == indexPath.section)
```

In that I have a button target  (`#selector(AnimateCollectionView)`).
I want to animate  tableCollectionCell which is at  (`1 == indexPath.section`).

See my  `AnimateCollectionView` method :-

```
func AnimateCollectionView() {
    let identifier = "TableCollectionCell"
    var tableCollectionCell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: identifier) as? TableCollectionCell

    if(tableCollectionCell == nil) {
        let nib:Array = Bundle.main.loadNibNamed("TableCollectionCell", owner: self, options: nil)!
        tableCollectionCell = nib[0] as? TableCollectionCell
        tableCollectionCell?.delegate = self
    }

    tableCollectionCell?.alpha = 0

    UIView.animate(withDuration: 1.50, animations: {
        //self.view.layoutIfNeeded()
        tableCollectionCell?.alpha = 1
    })
}
```

Comment: how do you want the second cell animate? rotate? scale ? move to right ? move to left ?

Comment: @aircraft I want to rotate.
Thanks

Comment: @Rob Thanks for reply.
Can you please tell me in code.
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

If you want to animate its change, you can just change some state variables, call [`tableView.reloadRows(at:with:)`](https://developer.apple.com/reference/uikit/uitableview/1614935-reloadrows), and have your `cellForRowAt` then check those state variables to know what the final cell should look like (i.e. whether it is the "before" or "after" cell configuration).

For example, here is an example, with two cells, toggling the second cell from red to blue cells.

```
class ViewController: UITableViewController {

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        tableView.register(UINib(nibName: "RedCell", bundle: nil), forCellReuseIdentifier: "RedCell")
        tableView.register(UINib(nibName: "BlueCell", bundle: nil), forCellReuseIdentifier: "BlueCell")
    }

    @IBAction func didTapButton(_ sender: UIButton) {
        isRedCell = !isRedCell
        tableView.reloadRows(at: [IndexPath(row: 1, section: 0)], with: .fade)
    }

    var isRedCell = true

    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return 2
    }

    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        if indexPath.row == 0 {
            let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "ButtonCell", for: indexPath)
            return cell
        } else if indexPath.row == 1 {
            if isRedCell {
                let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "RedCell", for: indexPath)
                return cell
            } else {
                let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "BlueCell", for: indexPath)
                return cell
            }
        }
        fatalError("There are only two rows in this demo")
    }

}
```

Now, assuming you really needed to use NIBs rather than cell prototypes, I would register the NIBs with the tableview like above, rather than having `cellForRow` have to manually instantiate them itself. Likewise, for my cell with the button, I just used a prototype cell in my storyboard and hooked the button directly to my `@IBOutlet`, avoiding a NIB for that cell entirely.

But all of that is unrelated to your main problem at hand: You can create your cells however you want. But hopefully this illustrates the basic idea, that on the tap of the button, I'm not trying to load any cells directly, but I just update some status variable that `cellForRow` will use to know which cell to load and then tell the `tableView` to animate the reloading of that `IndexPath`.

By the way, I assumed from your example that the two different potential cells for the second row required different NIBs. But if you didn't, it's even easier (use just one NIB and one cell identifier), but the idea is the same, just update your state variable and reload the second row with animation.

Comment: Actually there are 3 sections totally so 
I put those conditions. 
Thanks
Let me try this.